# Can multiple applications access the same credential manager record?

Tags: c#, windows, winmd, credential-manager, passwordvault

I am using below code in AppOne to add a credential to Web Credentials in Windows Credential Manager.

```
var vault = new Windows.Security.Credentials.PasswordVault();
vault.Add(new Windows.Security.Credentials.PasswordCredential("AAA", "user1", "password1"));
```

Then I would like to access it in AppTwo. I found AppTwo cannot access the record I saved above. I tested it out and seems only the application who saves the credential could access it. I think this makes sense. But is there a way I can save a credential in AppOne and fetch it in AppTwo? Can I save through the Windows Credentials instead of saving in Web Credentials in Credential Manager pro-grammatically by using C# API directly? And even if I can save the credential into the Windows credentials, can I share it between different applications?

My second question is if AppOne 1.0 saves a credential into credential manager, then AppOne is upgraded to 2.0, or if windows is upgraded from `win8` to `win10`, does the saved credential is still valid and correct? I search online but kind of get lost.

Thanks!!

Comment: I tested with publish an app with different version numbers, and it seems the same app with different version numbers can share credential stored in credential manager. That means AppOne 1.0 save a credential. AppOne 2.0 can retrieve it. I also tested with testing certificates. One application with certificate A stores a credential, then the same application with certificate B could fetch the credential.

Comment: I am curious how windows know my apps are two different apps? By what? Application names?